# Why isn't Spring Web/MVC adding my model attributes to the URL of my redirect view?

Tags: java, url, redirect, spring-mvc, model

Doing a redirect to GET after POST.
Spring Web should be adding the 'clientId' model attribute below onto my URL, but it's not....

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
    ClientID clientId = ((MyCommand) command).getClientId();
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()), "clientId", clientId);
}
```

The same problem occurs if I just pass `getSuccessView()` to the ModelAndView and put `redirect:<success_view_url>` as the success view in my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, `RedirectView` only commutes what it calls 'Simple Value Types' to the URL. c.f. `RedirectView.isEligibleValue()`.

The solution is to add the `ClientId` to the model as a `String` rather than the more custom type:

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
    ClientID clientId = ((MyCommand) command).getClientId();
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()), "clientId", clientId.toString());
}
```

**Note `.toString()` on the last line.**

You can override `isEligibleValue()` (on your own `RedirectView` subclass) is you really want to, but it's easier to just toString everything you put in there.